# How to save an excel file to different formats simultaneously

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on an excel file named **tracker.xls** .

- I make a few changes.
- When I "Save" the file , the changes will be saved to **tracker.xls**
- Then I do "Save as" and save it in **.html** format , so the file name changes to **tracker.htm**
- Next I make further changes to the file (which is apparently now **tracker.htm**).
- When I click on "Save" however, then changes only get recorded to **tracker.htm**
- The changes do not get recorded to **tracker.xls**

Is there a way to save the changes to both simultaneously?

Comment: You can't do it simultaneously, but you could do one after the other.  It isn't clear what your real goal is, though.  Do you want to keep the default storage format as, say, .xls, and export to .htm so the save action doesn't change the current/default storage format?

Comment: I want to be able to preview the excel file in my browser(offline). I have two links in my webpage one which will open the **tracker.htm** and the other which will open **tracker.xls** so I basically want them to be synchronised

Answer (score 0):

Excel can only save whatever file you are working on.  When you save as HTML, that becomes the current document.

However, it should be possible to work only on the XLS file and update the HTML file.  This would require VBA though.  I have never tried it, but there are two functions that would be key to me.

- [Workbook_BeforeSave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840057.aspx)
- [ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add](http://analystcave.com/excel-export-excel-to-html-convert-tables-html/)

You should be able to write VBA code so that when you save the XLS it will export to HTML automatically.

Comment: Let me try this out